# Special flights

Tags: pattern

1. What links

> Southwest Flight 3551
>
> Iberia Flight 3692
>
> Aeroflot Flight 6582

2. Can you name another flight in this unusual group?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The special property is that

> Each of the airport codes, are both 3-letter words that spell a 6-letter word together.
>
>  Southwest 3551 goes from Burbank to Denver -- the airport codes are BUR and DEN, which become BURDEN.
>  Iberia 3692 goes from Madrid to Manchester -- the airport codes are MAD and MAN, which become MADMAN.
>  Aeroflot 6582 goes from Perm to St. Petersburg -- the airport codes are PEE and LED, which become PEELED.

Another flight with this property is

> very difficult to find! The best I can do are Turkish Airlines TK717 (DEL - IST). and Southwest WN1925 (SAN - DAL), which all have components that aren't particularly satisfying.
>
>  DEL: Another name for the gradient operator (∇) in vector analysis.
>  IST: (informal) A follower of a belief system. (Also could refer to the suffix referring to someone who practices a belief system or field of study.)
>  SAN: An archaic Greek letter (ϡ), Japanese honorific, or Spanish for "saint".
>  DAL: Dried legumes, in Indian cuisine.

Comment: (And now I'll have my search recommendations flooded with flights to various places for the next week...)